# existing .net libraries to generate image with the following requirements

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am looking for an existing .net image library to generate an image with the following requirements.

1. An image with a solid color background.
2. On top of the solid background is a pattern (from a small image tiled across the base image on #1) where I should be able to set it's opacity. #1 and #2 completes the background
3. 3 text areas would be placed on top of the background. starting from fixed positions.
4. Should be able to set fonts, sizes, colors, position.

The image layout looks like this.

[image]

**EDIT:** Already accomplished this using GDI+ and ImageMagick. Thanks for answering

Comment: Was just about to post another answer... Well, here it is:

Yes. The library is called Windows Forms and it gives great control and customization over fonts/sizes/colors/positions. You just need to create a basic template, also known as UserControl, with the form designer, then create an instance of that Control at runtime and fill it as you please. Finally, using its DrawToBitmap (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, retrieve your image. Don't forget to dispose the Control when finished!

Comment: @BlackBear a very nice approach plus some work with imagemagick for the background would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ImageMagick. Is a powerful tool suite to create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images. Is free software

See: http://www.imagemagick.org

**Features and Capabilities**

Here are just a few examples of what ImageMagick can do:

Format conversion: convert an image from one format to another (e.g. PNG to JPEG).

Transform: resize, rotate, crop, flip or trim an image.

Transparency: render portions of an image invisible.

Draw: add shapes or text to an image.

Decorate: add a border or frame to an image.

Special effects: blur, sharpen, threshold, or tint an image.

Animation: create a GIF animation sequence from a group of images.

Text & comments: insert descriptive or artistic text in an image.

Image identification: describe the format and attributes of an image.

Composite: overlap one image over another.

Montage: juxtapose image thumbnails on an image canvas.

Generalized pixel distortion: correct for, or induce image distortions including perspective.

Morphology of shapes: extract features, describe shapes and recognize patterns in images.

Motion picture support: read and write the common image formats used in digital film work.

Image calculator: apply a mathematical expression to an image or image channels.

Discrete Fourier transform: implements the forward and inverse DFT.

Color management: accurate color management with color profiles or in lieu of-- built-in gamma compression or expansion as demanded by the colorspace.

High dynamic-range images: accurately represent the wide range of intensity levels found in real scenes ranging from the brightest direct sunlight to the deepest darkest shadows.

Encipher or decipher an image: convert ordinary images into unintelligible gibberish and back again.

Virtual pixel support: convenient access to pixels outside the image region.

Large image support: read, process, or write mega-, giga-, or tera-pixel image sizes.

Threads of execution support: ImageMagick is thread safe and most internal algorithms execute in parallel to take advantage of speed-ups offered by multicore processor chips.

Distributed pixel cache: offload intermediate pixel storage to one or more remote servers.

Heterogeneous distributed processing: certain algorithms are OpenCL-enabled to take advantage of speed-ups offered by executing in concert across heterogeneous platforms consisting 
of CPUs, GPUs, and other processors.

ImageMagick on the iPhone: convert, edit, or compose images on your iOS device such as the iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 2):

All the operations you have described can be performed using the functions in System.Drawing name space of the framework by using GDI+. You can use MSDN to search through how framework classes and functions perform those operations, or you can read a book on the subject like :[http://www.amazon.com/NET-Graphics-Programming-Experts-Voice-ebook/dp/B001D0HKN6/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001D0HKN6)